# Using Mocha/Chai to test React-Redux app with an Axios async call

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, react-redux, chai

I have a connected component which does this:

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage();
        this.props.fetchPlots();
    }
```

The first function returns a string, the second an array of objects.

First function:

```
export function fetchMessage() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(ROOT_URL, {
            headers: {
                authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
            })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_MESSAGE,
                    payload: response.data.message
                });
            });
    }
}
```

The second function is very similar.

Types are like this:

```
export const FETCH_MESSAGE = 'fetch_message';
```

Reducers follow this format:

```
case FETCH_MESSAGE:
            return { ...state, message: action.payload }
        case FETCH_PLOTS:
            return { ...state, plots: action.payload }
```

I want to test it with Mocha and Chai. I'm trying to pass state like this:

```
beforeEach(() =>
    {
        component = renderComponent(Component, null, {
            message: 'teststring',
            plots: [
                {...},{...},{...}
            ]
        });
    });
```

at which point, I get the following error:

```
  Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
      at dispatch (C:...\node_modules\redux\lib\createStore.js:165:13)
      at Object.fetchMessage (C:...\node_modules\redux\lib\bindActionCreators.js:7:12)
      at Dashboard.componentWillMount (C:.../src/components/component.js:9:20)
```

How can I simulate the action/pass the object into state without it puking on me?

Comment: Could you please share a complete example, like the redux setup/actions/...etc

Comment: @mshaaban I don't want to copy paste all the code in here, have updated the actions and reducers...

Comment: and you should dispatch the action not calling the action-creator directly, `dispatch(this.props.fetchMessage())`

Comment: @mshaaban where should I do that?